# Make MVC Web application to use default resource file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, resources, cultureinfo

I have an asp net MVC application that uses Resource files for translations. Some of these resource files are shared across a number of applications. Normally this works as expected:

```
ProjectX
- ClientStrings.resx     <--- this one is picked for swedish
- ClientStrings.en.resx  <--- this one is picked for english
Shared
- Shared.resx     <--- this one is picked for swedish
- Shared.en.resx  <--- this one is picked for english
```

My issue is with one application that shouldn't be translated to any other language - it should only use Swedish.

```
ProjectY
- ClientStrings.resx     <--- this one is picked (only one choice)   
Shared
- Shared.resx     
- Shared.en.resx     <--- ISSUE: this one is always picked (even for swedish)
```

The method used to change languange is by changing browser language. Please help me understand why this doesn't work for ProjectY!

Comment: When debugging what are the values of `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` and `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture`?

Comment: probably you should change the `ClientStrings.resx` to `ClientStrings.<culture>.resx`

Comment: @CodeNotFound The issue doesn't occur while debugging, and the culture is swedish.

Comment: @Rahul Will try this, thanks!

Comment: I didn't say that the bug occur **only** when debugging. I said when you debug the code what is the actual values of the properties I put on my first comment. Thoses values determine which files to pick for localization.

Comment: @CodeNotFound I don't have direct access to the environment running the code where the issue occur (unfortunately). What I can say is that when I run this locally (without the issue occurring) I get the values sv-se and sv respectively. If as you say these values determines the file chosen, the real question is why this doesn't apply for ProjectY when it works perfectly for ProjectX. Please let me know if any more information about the projects can help!

Comment: @Rahul Creating a ClientStrings.sv-se.resx didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue lay in applying the browser's language. Comparing the two project web.config-files I found that the following line is required for the browser language to apply, and was missing in ProjectY:

```
<globalization enableClientBasedCulture="true" uiCulture="auto" culture="auto"></globalization>
```